# Which is the best OS for ForgeRock products (i.e. AM, IDM, DS and IG) to be used in Docker container?

Tags: docker, operating-system, forgerock, openidm

Currently Forgerock is providing different OS for different products for docker container (below list):

AM(v6.5.2) available on Debian-9 
IDM(v6.5.0) is available on CentOS 7.7.1908 
DS(v6.5.2) is available on Ubuntu 18.04.2 
IG(v6.5.1) is available On Alpine 3.9.4

We want to use single flavor of OS for these deployments on ForgeRock products.
So my Question is- Which OS I should go for preparing the Docker image?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best is Centos/Red Hat since there is more documentation of deployments on this environment.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, in terms of the ForgeRock stack (apart from the WebAgents) - it doesn't really matter because they all run within a JVM. What JDK you choose will have more bearing, but in terms of distribution, it's up to you and whatever you feel aligns with your deployment best.